# How do I capture client-side external URL clicks in the IIS logs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, logging

I'm hosting an **ASP.NET 4.0 MVC** application and looking for some alternatives to capture, in the IIS server logs, client-side external URLs that are *clicked on* by  **visitors**?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a "dummy" page on your site, for example, "logExternalClick".  Then code the externally pointing links in such a way that an ajax request is first made to your page, e.g. "logExternalClick?extURL=www.google.com" <-- be sure to URL encode the value of the extURL parameter.